# Troubles modifying a set with multiple iterators

Tags: java, iterator

I'd like to compare elements within a set, in order to merge elements too similar. In order to gain some time, I would like to erase similarities during the iteration.
Here how I try to proceed:

```
Iterator<Personne> i1 = personnes.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext()) {
     Personne personneObservee = i1.next();
     Set<Personne> tmp = new HashSet<Personne>();
     tmp.addAll(personnes);
     Iterator<Personne> i2 = tmp.iterator();
     while (i2.hasNext()) {
        Personne autrePersonne = i2.next();
        if (personneObservee.isSimilarTo(autrePersonne)) {
            personnes.remove(autrePersonne);
        }
    }
    result.add(personneObservee.toString());
}
```

As you can guess from my presence here, it doesn't work, giving me this nice stacktrace :

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:926)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:960)
        at NameDetectorWithBenefits.mergeSamePersons(NameDetectorWithBenefits.java:41)
        at App.main(App.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

At first, I thought i1 and i2 were iterating over the same set and that I would find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268399/java-multiple-iterators-on-a-set-removing-proper-subsets-and-concurrentmodific). As a consequence, I create a temporary set each time. However, it didn't resolve the problem.

Any ideas where the trouble might come from ?

Comment: How does your `isSimilarTo(Personne)` differ from the code that would be inside `equals(Object)`?

Comment: It has some calculations over the differents attributes but reads onlyinformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iterating through a set use the iterator to delete elements from  the set rather than using set.remove()

```
// wrong way
personnes.remove(autrePersonne); 

//correct way
it.remove();
```

Comment: It erased the exception, thanks ! I'll check if it works as expected tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Iterator#remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) rather than [`Set#remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

So replace the following line

```
personnes.remove(autrePersonne);
```

with

```
i2.remove();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-java-iterator-next) for more details.

Comment: Although this is correct, how do you apply this to his particular example?

Comment: Is there a difference between `It#remove` and `It.remove` or is this just convention ?

Comment: @fxm `Iterator#remove()` simply refers to the `remove()` method of the `Iterator` class. In your code you'd call that method on your `Iterator` object (i.e. `12.remove()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the `SET` while another thread is iterating it due to which `ConcurrentModificationException` exception arise.

You are iterating the SET

`Iterator<Personne> i1 = personnes.iterator();` and use  `personnes.remove(autrePersonne);` to remove the element.

use Iterator `remove` method to remove the element

Comment: But you cant update parent SET while iterating.Also what is ur desired output ?

Comment: A set containing elements which aren't similars.

Comment: you are using set so it will not contain similar entry

Comment: Well, similar in my way, not strictly equal (hence the `isSimilar` function).

Comment: what isSimilarTo method do /

Comment: It has some calculations over the differents attributes It only reads information, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

1. isolate what need removal
2. remove

.

```
final Set<Personne> toRemove = new HashSet<>();
for (final Personne personne: personnes) {
    for (final Personne autrePersonne: personnes) {
        if (person.isSimilarTo(autrePersonne)) {
            toRemove.add(autrePersonne);
        }
    }
}
personnes.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Also, you need to take care of the case where autrePersonne equals personne

Comment: While it probably works, it's more expensive in terms of complexity than what I'm trying to achieve.